# How to disable strict mode at MySql in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I tried recently to use MySql with an external database on a distant  server, but whenever I try to make a default value on a Text/Blob I get an error message.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'BLOB/TEXT column 'prefix' can't have 
a default value'
```

Apperantly the problem lies about a bug that occurs for windows only...(?)

I'm using C# on the Visual Studio environment.
I got the MySql packages using Nuget. but I'v seen no guides online that tell me how to disable the Strict mode  on the Visual studio environment.

I don't have any my.ini files on my computer, since I didn't install any Mysql files, as mentioned above, I used Nuget to get the packages for my project.

If possible, can you tell me how to disable the strict mode that will allow me to use the default value on Text/Blob?

Edit:
For those who want to see the sql line here it is:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servers_preferneces (server_id TEXT,prefix TEXT DEFAULT '/', days_to_be_missing INT DEFAULT 3, excused_rank_name TEXT DEFAULT 'AWOL', " +
        "excused_rank_id TEXT DEFAULT '', missing_rank_name TEXT DEFAULT 'MIA', missing_rank_id TEXT DEFAULT NULL, welcome_state INTEGER DEFAULT 0, welcome_message TEXT DEFAULT ''," +
        " welcome_channel_id TEXT DEFAULT 'DEFAULT'); ";
```

It suppose to be executed using the following code lines:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, db_connection);
MySqlDataReader reader;
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: What error messsge?

Comment: What is the output of command SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';

Comment: @Leonardo It shows blank as the value.
Something fishy is going on here...

Comment: What is the SQL statement you're trying to execute? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Server doesn't support `DEFAULT` values for `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns; this is a [known issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21532) of the database engine.

If the server is running in strict mode, this will generate the error you're seeing. If the server is not in strict mode, it will just be a warning.

However, your code still won't work properly, even if you turned off strict mode on the server: rows would be inserted with `NULL`s, not the `DEFAULT` value you specified.

The fix is to change your schema to not have a `DEFAULT` value, and to explicitly insert the defaults you want in your `INSERT` statements.

```
-- SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servers_preferneces
(
    server_id TEXT,
    prefix TEXT,
    days_to_be_missing INT DEFAULT 3,
    excused_rank_name TEXT,
    excused_rank_id TEXT,
    missing_rank_name TEXT,
    missing_rank_id TEXT,
    welcome_state INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    welcome_message TEXT,
    welcome_channel_id TEXT );

// C#
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO servers_preferneces(prefix,
        excused_rank_name, excused_rank_id, missing_rank_name
        welcome_message, welcome_channel_id)
        VALUES(@prefix, @excused_rank_name, @excused_rank_id,
        @missing_rank_name, @welcome_message, @welcome_channel_id);";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prefix", "/");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@excused_rank_name", "AWOL");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@excused_rank_id", "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@missing_rank_name", "MIA");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@welcome_message", "");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@welcome_channel_id", "DEFAULT");
    // add other parameters

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```